# SQL Queries in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm constructing a Data Access Object within a project utilizing the Yii framework.  One of the insert queries is relatively complicated as it is spread out over three related tables.

At this time, I have the SQL queries written out, and am not using QueryBuilder.

At the beginning of the insert function, I have

```
$connection = Yii::app()->db;
$transaction = $connection->beginTransaction();

try {
  $command = $connection->createCommand($this->insertQuestion);

  //multiple $command->bindParam() calls
```

According to the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder#building-data-manipulation-queries), a `CDbCommand` instance can be reused to build multiple queries.  However, `CdbCommand::reset` must be called when reusing for a new query.

This only appears within the QueryBuilder portion of the documentation.  As I'm using `CdbCommand::bindParam` to bind variables to the query without using QueryBuilder, is it necessary for me to do

```
$command->reset();
$command->setText($sqlText);
$command->bindParam("sqlVar", $variable, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Is it possible to skip using `CDbCommand::reset` in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you can do something like:

```
$transaction=$connection->beginTransaction();
try
{
   $connection->createCommand($sql1)->execute();
   $connection->createCommand($sql2)->execute();
   //.... other SQL executions
   $transaction->commit();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
   $transaction->rollback();
}
```

If you know the SQL you want to use, just use that for $sql1, $sql2, and $sql3.